# Ceph non-replicated pool (replication 1)

Tags: ceph

I have a 10 node cluster. I want to create a non-replicated pool
(replication 1) and I want to ask some questions about it:

Let me tell you my use case:

- I don't care about losing data,
- All of my data is JUNK and these junk files are usually between 1KB to 32MB.
- These files will be deleted in 5 days.
- Writable space and I/O speed is more important.
- I have high Write/Read/Delete operations, minimum 200GB a day.

I'm afraid that, in any failure, I won't be able to access the whole
cluster. Losing data is okay but I have to ignore missing files,
remove the data from the cluster and continue with existing data and
while doing this, I want to be able to write new data to the cluster.

My questions are:
1- To reach this goal do you have any recommendations?
2- With this setup, what potential problems do you have in mind?
3- I think Erasure Coding is not a choice because of the performance
problems and slow file deletion. With this I/O need EC will miss files
and leaks may happen (I've seen before on Nautilus).
4- You read my needs, is there a better way to do this? Maybe an alternative for ceph?

Thank you for the answers.
Best regards.

Comment: Is Ceph a requirement? If you don't want replication why not just use a simple NFS server (or similar)? If Ceph is a requirement you probably would need to interact with it more often than usually necessary. For example, if you loose an OSD or entire host you would need to mark those PGs as lost, it makes things more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Currently I'm using ZFS with raidz1 but dealing with 10 different NFS endpoint is hard, and its also hard for software development. I've decided using ceph and librados instead of NFS. Now I just don't want to use Replication 2 because this data is not important. In my case, I don't care about losing data and also it will happen only a failure so with ceph tuning I will ignore lost pg's so on.